# Mounting an iso in ubuntu 14

Tags: mount, iso

I want to know please  if i can mount an iso (virtual drive) ?

I need to mount it like daemon tools in windows

I tried cdemu but it dosen't work for me

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install acetoneiso
```

Acetoneiso:feature-rich  graphical  application to mount and manage CD/DVD images
Opens a graphical filemanager which lets you mount typical  proprietary images  formats of the Windows world such as ISO BIN NRG MDF IMG and do     plenty of other things.
If FILE is specified, then the program mounts the image before  opening the GUI.
A  detailed  manual  for  acetoneiso  can be found from the menu of the    graphical filemanger in `Help -> Manual`.

Comment: I can't load the iso it's says error , 



the iso is a full bluray of a movie

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this via the command line, you will first need a place to mount the ISO to, then you can mount it to that location.

Try This:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cd1
sudo mount /home/{user}/filename.iso /media/cd1 -o loop
```

Be sure to change `/home/{user}/filename.iso` to the actual location and name of the ISO file you wish to access. You *might* see a message afterwards telling you that the ISO is read-only, but it can be ignored:

```
mount: /media/cd1: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
```

From this point, you can access the location like any other:

```
cd /media/cd1
ls -AlF
```

Alternatively, if you are using Nautilus, then after completing the steps above, you may go into Nautilus and click on the ISO in the sidebar, just as you would with a CD/DVD